# Is it possible to change the asmx webservice interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services

I am looking for how to change my **WebService.asmx** interface which is generated automatically; an upper blue bar with "WebService" in white, then text saying

> The following operations are supported...

is it possible to design that interface in my own style?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to change that?

Comment: Because I need it for some customers who want to test the webservice

Comment: As far as I am aware the UI cannot be edited. The customer will need to have some sort of application that needs to use the webservice for them to test it

Comment: I am not sure that editing the interface is possible either. but I can see there is a way to add comments to each function for example that's why there may be a way to edit the whole interface

Comment: The comments would probably be something that you would add as an attribute in the asmx file. Sorry that I cannot be of any further help.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherTrevor